# How to display a same website in different language?

Tags: locale

I have completed a website in magento1.9.2.3. Now I wish to have the same site in different languages. How to translate the whole website into different language? Do I have to translate description of each product manually? Is it such tedious task? Kindly someone help me to do that.

Also with little knowledge regarding this I googled for language package of malay.But  It is not available for magento 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Magento string you can find translations (you have to check if at least one exists for your language).

For products you have to translate each product as well as CMS pages and blocks.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me to find the language pack of malay for magento1.9.2.3?Because the links which I searched is not providing the correct extension key

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up multistore.

please visit link bellow:-

https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/setup-multiple-languages-currencies/

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Exactly, that's the way to go. Using a multistore solution with multiple store fronts you can create a setup that allows URLs like www.yourwebsite.com/de and www.yourwebsite.com/fr for example.

Comment: thank you. But i am unable to find the language pack.

Comment: there is app > locale in magento